# Formatted bootloader by mistake and phone won't turn on (device: MT6570)

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, bootloader, partitions, device-firmware

I have a Techno Spark 3 with a MT6570 chip and i used the SP Flash Tool to flash the ROM but i kept getting the error STATUS_PARTITION_NOT_FOUND, so i thought that if i format the bootloader it would help but instead i have a dead phone which cannot even come on when you press the power button.

I also wish to know if i am using the correct ROM because my phone seems to be a clone and it cannot accept any of the newer chips MT6971 0r MT6580 i have attached the phone's about section so that you could tell me which exact model it is.

[image] [image]

Comment: MediaTek based phones are typically flashed when the device is powered down/off. Have you tried to connect the device to a PC?

Comment: It is dead so even if i connect it to a pc nothing happens, it was working well before i formated the bootloader